# Change 3d array to 4d array numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

From following code, I have got 'log_specgrams' with shape (20,1,12060). 
I want to change the shape to (20, 60, 201, 1). 
So I wrote the code like this.

```
log_specgrams = np.asarray(log_specgrams).reshape(len(log_specgrams), 60, 201, 1)
```

But I gave an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/for-test.py", line 26, in <module>
    features = extract_features(parent_dir,sub_dirs)
  File "D:/for-test.py", line 17, in extract_features
    log_specgrams = np.asarray(log_specgrams).reshape(len(log_specgrams), 60, 201, 1)
  File "C:\Users\CHS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 482, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (12060) into shape (1)
(1, 12060)
```

The whole code:

```
import glob
import os
import librosa
import numpy as np

def extract_features(parent_dir, sub_dirs, file_ext="*.wav"):
        log_specgrams = []
        for l, sub_dir in enumerate(sub_dirs):
                for fn in glob.glob(os.path.join(parent_dir, sub_dir, file_ext)):
                        X_in, sample_rate = librosa.load(fn)
                        melspec = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=X_in, sr=sample_rate, n_fft=1024, hop_length=441, n_mels=60)
                        logmel = librosa.logamplitude(melspec)
                        logmel = logmel.T.flatten()[:, np.newaxis].T
                        log_specgrams.append(logmel)

        print(np.shape(logmel))
        log_specgrams = np.asarray(log_specgrams).reshape(len(log_specgrams), 60, 201, 1)
        print(np.shape(log_specgrams))
        A = features

        return np.array(log_specgrams)


parent_dir = 'Sound-Data_small'
sub_dirs= ['fold1','fold2']
features = extract_features(parent_dir,sub_dirs)
```

I really want to change the shape of 'log_specgrams', (20,1,12060) to (20, 60, 201, 1).

Comment: The error appears to occur in `asarray`, i.e. before you even get to reshape. Perhaps the contents of `log_specgrams` are not homogeneous?

Comment: Does a simple `reshape` work?  Test it with smaller sizes so you can see what is going on.  What's the significance of that size `1` dimension?  Why the flip in position?

Comment: Yes. The error occur in asarry. Because I'm a beginner about Python, so I don't understand your question (homogeneous?) Can you tell me more simply? If it is 'homogeneous', there is a solution?

Comment: I'm modeling the CNN based structure. I wanna extract features from audio files and use them as a training data. So I need feature matrix with shape of (num of features, width, height, dimension). I don't need a multi-dimension, since I use audio features.

Comment: I just meant perhaps the elements do not have the same shape. For example if you try to convert `[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [[1,2,3],[3,4],[5,6]]]` to an array it will not work. Essentially because the elments cannot be cast in a rectangular pattern. Something similar may be causing your problems.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Panzer. When I saw your comment, checked the data and it was a length problem. There were several different lengths of data. So there was another element of shape. Oh my godness. It was very elementary mistake. I think I should remove this question.

Comment: happens to the best @HSCho

Answer (score 1):

Reshape takes the parameters as a tuple, i.e.

```
log_specgrams = np.asarray(log_specgrams).reshape((len(log_specgrams), 60, 201, 1))
```

or

```
log_specgrams = np.asarray(log_specgrams).reshape((None, 60, 201, 1))
```

None computes the missing dimension itself

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I had a same error. Do you have a another opinion? (solution?)

Comment: Just an addition, `reshape(-1, 60, 201, 1)` works the same way as `None`.

Comment: In fact, in a recent numpy (1.11.1) `None` returns an error while `-1` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input is `(20,1,12060)` and the desired output is `(20, 60, 201, 1)` with the `1` dimension swapped, the following should work just fine:

```
data = np.asarray(log_specgrams)
data = data.swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(20, 60, 201, 1)
```

Example with random data:

```
>>> data = np.random.randn(20, 1, 12060)
>>> data.shape
(20, 1, 12060)
```

Then,

```
>>> data = data.swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(20, 60, 201, 1)
>>> data.shape
(20, 60, 201, 1)
```

It can be noted that the operation has two components. The first part swapes the 2nd and 3rd axis, transforming the data from `(20, 1, 12060)` to `(20, 12060, 1)`. The second part divides the 2nd axis `12060` in two new ones of size `60 x 201`.

It works for arbitrary axes of different size, but for axes of size `1` that require no data rearranging, `data.reshape(20, 60, 201, 1)` or @yar's answer with a single `reshape` might be more straight forward. This solution just extends to other problems with axis size different from `1`.